# Quick Edit disable add new column

Tags: sharepoint-server, quick-edit

I've already tried disabling it via css 
but if you hide the hole column you can't add new records , if you hide the plus symbol you'll get nevertheless the hover menue.

e.g. hide the plus with CSS:

```
ms-addcolumn-icon{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

hide the whole column JavaScript:

```
  jQuery("#spgridcontainer_WPQ7_leftpane_mainTable").find('th:last-child, td:last-child').remove();
```

Anybody out there with an override context example or some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below CSS it is working on my SharePoint online site. It is hiding the last column

```
.ms-listviewgrid .ms-viewheadertr th:last-child,
.ms-listviewgrid tr td:last-child
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add comments yet, i would like to improve @Venkat Konjeti's answer a little bit.
If you are using `display: none;` , it doesn't work properly, you are not able to use choose columns or date picker, because it throw the option away.

```
.ms-listviewgrid .ms-viewheadertr th:last-child,
.ms-listviewgrid tr td:last-child
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

All credits to Venkat Konjeti's answer.